# JavaScript classes, how does one apply "Separation of Concerns" and "Don't repeat Yourself" (DRY) in practice

Tags: javascript, class, widget, dry, separation-of-concerns

I'm just in the process of learning how JavaScript classes work and I'm just looking for some advice on how to achieve something quite simple I hope regarding animating some elements.

I have created a class named `myAnimation`, the constructor takes in 1 argument which is an element. All its doing is fading a heading out and in, all very simple. It works fine when there is just one heading element on the page, I'm just not to sure how I go about getting it to work with more than one heading.

Please excuse my naivety with this; it's all very new to me, this is just a basic example I have managed to make myself to try and help myself understand how it works.

```js
class myAnimation {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = document.querySelector(element);
  }
  fadeOut(time) {
    if (this.element.classList.contains('fadeout-active')) {
      this.element.style.opacity = 1;
      this.element.classList.remove('fadeout-active');
      button.textContent = 'Hide Heading';
    } else {
      this.element.style.opacity = 0;
      this.element.style.transition = `all ${time}s ease`;
      this.element.classList.add('fadeout-active');
      button.textContent = 'Show Heading';
    }
  }
}

const heading = new myAnimation('.heading');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  heading.fadeOut(1);

});
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="heading">Intro Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the intro section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1 class="heading">Main Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the main section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to create a `myAnimation` for all headings or each one individually? The way you've defined it now, `myAnimation` has only 1 element it cares about.

Comment: I suggest passing the specific html element directly to the constructor. Let the query part get done by another task. Right now you have two elements that are classified as `.heading`. The query in the current constructor, due to `document.querySelector`, does only return one element. Right now always the fist heading element that occurs in the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my comment I wanted to make the script run in a way I thought it might have been intended by the OP.

Even though it demonstrates what needs to be done in order to run properly, the entire base design proofs to be not fitting to what the OP really might need to achieve.

The class is called `Animation` but from the beginning it was intermingling element-animation and changing state of a single somehow globally scoped `button`.

Even though running now, the design does not proof to be a real fit because one now passes the element that is going to be animated and the button it shall interact with altogether into the constructor.

The functionality is grouped correctly, just the place and the naming doesn't really fit.

The OP might think about a next iteration step of the provided code ...

```js
class Animation {
  constructor(elementNode, buttonNode) {

    this.element = elementNode;
    this.button = buttonNode;

    // only in case both elements were passed ...
    if (elementNode && buttonNode) {
    
      // couple them by event listening/handling.
      buttonNode.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // - accessing the `Animation` instance's `this` context
        //   gets assured by making use of an arrow function.
        this.fadeOut(1);
      });
    }
  }
  fadeOut(time) {
    if (this.element.classList.contains('fadeout-active')) {

      this.element.style.opacity = 1;
      this.element.classList.remove('fadeout-active');

      this.button.textContent = 'Hide Heading';
    } else {
      this.element.style.opacity = 0;
      this.element.style.transition = `all ${time}s ease`;
      this.element.classList.add('fadeout-active');

      this.button.textContent = 'Show Heading';
    }
  }
}

function initializeAnimations() {
  // get list of all elements that have a `heading` class name.
  const headingList = document.querySelectorAll('.heading');

  // for each heading element do ...
  headingList.forEach(function (headingNode) {
    // ... access its parent element and query again for a single button.
    const buttonNode = headingNode.parentElement.querySelector('.button');
    
    // if the related button element exists ...
    if (buttonNode) {

      // ... create a new `Animation` instance.
      new Animation(headingNode, buttonNode);
    }
  });
}

initializeAnimations();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="heading">Intro Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the intro section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1 class="heading">Main Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the main section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>
```

***... new day, next possible iteration step ...***

The 2nd iteration separates concerns.

It does so by renaming the class and implementing only class specific behavior. Thus a `FadeToggle` class provides just *toggle specific* functionality.

The code then gets split into two functions that handle initialization. For better reuse the initializing code and the html structure need to be refactored into something more generic. The `data` attribute of each container that features a trigger-element for fading a target element will be used as a configuration storage that provides all necessary information for the initializing process. (One even can provide individual transition duration values.)

Last there is a handler function that is implemented in a way that it can be reused by `bind` in order to generate a closure which provides all the necessary data for each *trigger-target couple.*

```js
class FadeToggle {
  // a clean fade-toggle implementation.
  constructor(elementNode, duration) {

    duration = parseFloat(duration, 10);
    duration = Number.isFinite(duration) ? duration : 1;

    elementNode.style.opacity = 1;
    elementNode.style.transition = `all ${ duration }s ease`;

    this.element = elementNode;
  }

  isFadeoutActive() {
    return this.element.classList.contains('fadeout-active');
  }

  toggleFade(duration) {
    duration = parseFloat(duration, 10);
    if (Number.isFinite(duration)) {

      this.element.style.transitionDuration = `${ duration }s`;
    }
    if (this.isFadeoutActive()) {

      this.element.style.opacity = 1;
      this.element.classList.remove('fadeout-active');
    } else {
      this.element.style.opacity = 0;
      this.element.classList.add('fadeout-active');
    }
  }
}

function handleFadeToggleWithBoundContext(/* evt */) {
  const { trigger, target } = this;

  if (target.isFadeoutActive()) {
    trigger.textContent = 'Hide Heading';
  } else {
    trigger.textContent = 'Show Heading';
  }
  target.toggleFade();
}

function initializeFadeToggle(elmNode) {
  // parse an element node's fade-toggle configuration.
  const config = JSON.parse(elmNode.dataset.fadeToggleConfig || null);

  const selectors = (config && config.selectors);
  if (selectors) {
    try {
      // query both the triggering and the target element
      const trigger = elmNode.querySelector(selectors.trigger || null);
      let target = elmNode.querySelector(selectors.target || null);

      if (trigger && target) {

        // create a `FadeToggle` target type.
        target = new FadeToggle(target, config.duration);

        // couple trigger and target by event listening/handling ...
        trigger.addEventListener(
          'click',
          handleFadeToggleWithBoundContext.bind({
            // ... and binding both as context properties to the handler.
            trigger,
            target
          })
        );
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      console.warn(exception.message, exception);
    }
  }
}

function initializeEveryFadeToggle() {
  // get list of all elements that contain a fade-toggle configuration
  const configContainerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-fade-toggle-config]');

  // do initialization for each container separately.
  configContainerList.forEach(initializeFadeToggle);
}

initializeEveryFadeToggle();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="intro" data-fade-toggle-config='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target":".heading"},"duration":3}'>
  <h1 class="heading">Intro Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the intro section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>

<div class="main" data-fade-toggle-config='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target":".heading"}}'>
  <h1 class="heading">Main Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the main section</p>
  <button class="button">Hide Heading</button>
</div>
```

***... afternoon, improve the handling of state changes ...***

There is still hard wired data, written directly into the code. In order to get rid of string-values that will be (re)rendered every time a toggle-change takes place one might give the `data`-based configuration-approach another chance.

This time each triggering element might feature a configuration that provides state depended values. Thus the initialization process needs to take care of retrieving this data and also of rendering it according to the initial state of a fade-toggle target.

This goal directly brings up the necessity of a render function for a trigger element because one needs to change a trigger's state not only initially but also with every fade-toggle.

And this again will change the handler function in a way that in addition it features bound state values too in order to delegate such data to the render process ...

```js
class FadeToggle {
  // a clean fade-toggle implementation.
  constructor(elementNode, duration) {

    duration = parseFloat(duration, 10);
    duration = Number.isFinite(duration) ? duration : 1;

    elementNode.style.opacity = 1;
    elementNode.style.transition = `all ${ duration }s ease`;

    this.element = elementNode;
  }

  isFadeoutActive() {
    return this.element.classList.contains('fadeout-active');
  }

  toggleFade(duration) {
    duration = parseFloat(duration, 10);
    if (Number.isFinite(duration)) {

      this.element.style.transitionDuration = `${ duration }s`;
    }
    if (this.isFadeoutActive()) {

      this.element.style.opacity = 1;
      this.element.classList.remove('fadeout-active');
    } else {
      this.element.style.opacity = 0;
      this.element.classList.add('fadeout-active');
    }
  }
}

function renderTargetStateDependedTriggerText(target, trigger, fadeinText, fadeoutText) {
  if ((fadeinText !== null) && (fadeoutText !== null)) {
    if (target.isFadeoutActive()) {

      trigger.textContent = fadeinText;
    } else {
      trigger.textContent = fadeoutText;
    }
  }
}

function handleFadeToggleWithBoundContext(/* evt */) {
  // retrieve context data.
  const { target, trigger, fadeinText, fadeoutText } = this;

  target.toggleFade();

  renderTargetStateDependedTriggerText(
    target,
    trigger,
    fadeinText,
    fadeoutText
  );
}

function initializeFadeToggle(elmNode) {
  // parse an element node's fade-toggle configuration.
  let config = JSON.parse(elmNode.dataset.fadeToggleConfig || null);

  const selectors = (config && config.selectors);
  if (selectors) {
    try {
      // query both the triggering and the target element
      const trigger = elmNode.querySelector(selectors.trigger || null);
      let target = elmNode.querySelector(selectors.target || null);

      if (trigger && target) {

        // create a `FadeToggle` target type.
        target = new FadeToggle(target, config.duration);

        // parse a trigger node's fade-toggle configuration and state.
        const triggerStates = ((
          JSON.parse(trigger.dataset.fadeToggleTriggerConfig || null)
          || {}
        ).states || {});

        // get a trigger node's state change values.
        const fadeinStateValues = (triggerStates.fadein || {});
        const fadeoutStateValues = (triggerStates.fadeout || {});

        // get a trigger node's state change text contents.
        const fadeinText = fadeinStateValues.textContent || null;
        const fadeoutText = fadeoutStateValues.textContent || null;

        // rerender trigger node's initial text value.
        renderTargetStateDependedTriggerText(
          target,
          trigger,
          fadeinText,
          fadeoutText
        );

        // couple trigger and target by event listening/handling ...
        trigger.addEventListener(
          'click',
          handleFadeToggleWithBoundContext.bind({
            // ... and by binding both and some text values
            // that are sensitive to state changes
            // as context properties to the handler.
            target,
            trigger,
            fadeinText,
            fadeoutText
          })
        );
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      console.warn(exception.message, exception);
    }
  }
}

function initializeEveryFadeToggle() {
  // get list of all elements that contain a fade-toggle configuration
  const configContainerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-fade-toggle-config]');

  // do initialization for each container separately.
  configContainerList.forEach(initializeFadeToggle);
}

initializeEveryFadeToggle();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="intro" data-fade-toggle-config='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target":".heading"},"duration":3}'>
  <h1 class="heading">Intro Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the intro section</p>
  <button class="button" data-fade-toggle-trigger-config='{"states":{"fadeout":{"textContent":"Hide Heading"},"fadein":{"textContent":"Show Heading"}}}'>Toggle Heading</button>
</div>

<div class="main" data-fade-toggle-config='{"selectors":{"trigger":".button","target":".heading"}}'>
  <h1 class="heading">Main Heading</h1>
  <p>This is the main section</p>
  <button class="button">Toggle Heading</button>
</div>
```

Comment: on the `The 2nd iteration...` snippet, on `trigger.addEventListener` why are you adding `false` as a third parameter? I believe it is `false` by default which means `event-bubbling` happens.

Comment: ... it's an old days habit. One can/should omit it.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota ... fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `document.querySelector(".button")` only returns the first element with class `.button` [(reference)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

You might want to try `document.querySelectorAll(".button")` [(reference)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) to add your event listeners.

(Though this will only toggle your first heading - for the very same reason. ;))